# 50px border radius looks cracked in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, css

I am using `border-radius: 50px;` to make a round border. It works perfectly in Chrome and some other browsers, but it looks cracked in Firefox:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

This is how it looks in Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
li {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    width: 50px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 47px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mUkw/)

Comment: 1) You don't need to set border-radius to 50%. You can also set it to a ridiculous high amount, like 500px.
2) It's not just the borders that look bad. Look at the you-tube logo. It's hardly legible in FF. Could it be a matter of the anti-aliasing setting you use? Are you using character icons for the images?

Comment: Some rendering issue, I found same thing happened with chrome before 2 months.

Comment: @Ideogram icons are from font awesome. the same happens when i give radius 50px

Comment: Have you indeed included anti-aliasing settings in CSS? It's not just using anti-aliasing, it's also a matter of picking the right setting. This is what the icomoon  app suggests: >>> -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

Comment: if i increase the width of border by 1px its perfect. but that will make issues with other browsers

Comment: @AnjuRaghunath Is this all the code? I do not believe it's enough to reproduce the problem. If you're using glyphs, we would expect to find a css statement specifying the font used and a piece of html or css specifying which character we're looking at. As EaterOfCode mentions, please re-create this is as a jsfiddle. (--> http://jsfiddle.net/ )

Answer (score 0):

if You use: Font-Awesome

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
```

CSS:

```
body {background: #000;}
a {display:block; width: 50px; height:50px; border-radius:50%; color:#fff; border:1px solid #fff; text-align:center; line-height:50px;}
a i {font-size:25px; line-height: 50px;}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x3dTy/)

Comment: add border size :) border: 2px solid #fff;